# Why am I still seeing the MOTD when I log in over SSH?

Tags: bash, ssh, sshd, bashrc, motd

This is a fresh and clean headless *Debian 8.7* system, kernel *3.16.0-4-amd64*..

When I log in over SSH, I get that ugly Debian copyright notice:

> The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
>   the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
>   individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.
>
> Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
>   permitted by applicable law.

I don't know why that message is being displayed. It's been disabled in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
```

It's not being called from `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`. The message is even being displayed before the contents of `/etc/profile` and `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

There is not even an `/etc/update-motd.d` directory, just a static `/etc/motd` file. Where is this file magically being opened from?

Comment: @Fox Yep, it contains the string `Debian GNU/Linux 8 \n \l`, but is never actually displayed when I log in.

Answer (score 9):

On Debian-derived systems, even with `PrintMotd` set to `no` in the `sshd_config`, the MOTD is still presented as part of a PAM configuration.

For instance, on my Ubuntu (and thus Debian-derived) system, in my `/etc/pam.d/sshd`, I see:

```
# Print the message of the day upon successful login.
# This includes a dynamically generated part from /run/motd.dynamic
# and a static (admin-editable) part from /etc/motd.
session    optional     pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic
session    optional     pam_motd.so noupdate
```

Commenting these out may suppress the message you are trying to eliminate.

Answer (score 1):

Try `touch ~/.hush_login` on the remote host to suppress motd and a few other things. Better than tampering with sshd config IMO.